# Show scrollbars on ItemsControl item

Tags: c#, wpf

How can every item inside the ItemsControl - here it is a TextBox - show vertical scrollbars ?

I do not want a vertical scrollbar around all Expanders.

Thats the code I tried:

```
<ItemsControl ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ErrorLogs}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizationMode="Recycling"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>                       
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Expander Margin="0"  Header="{Binding FileName}" Background="Green">
                <Controls:BindableTextBox Background="Red"                                         
                    Text="{Binding Content, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Put it in a ScrollViewer?

Comment: I have done this before, but I want that each TextBox gets it scrollbar vertically not the ItemsControl

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

1, wrap inside a scrollviewer

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Expander Margin="0"
              Header="{Binding FileName}"
              Background="Green">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <Controls:BindableTextBox Background="Red"
                                      Text="{Binding Content, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Expander>
</DataTemplate>
```

2, enable multiline on textbox

eg.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Expander Margin="0"
              Header="{Binding FileName}"
              Background="Green">
        <TextBox Background="Red"
                 AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 Text="{Binding Content, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </Expander>
</DataTemplate>
```

I am not sure about Controls:BindableTextBox so using multiline depends on availability

Comment: I have to use the BindableTextBox which is a Winforms TextBox inherited from WindowsFormsHost. There I set textBox.Multiline = true;
            textBox.WordWrap = true;. The Scrollbars vertically are visible but grayed out LOL although there is enough text which is overflowing the whole layout.

Comment: You may specify the max height to the text box, so it grows to the desired height only, then scrollbar become active.